# Nesting Jquery-UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, nested

I am trying to nest jquery-ui tabs to create a page like this:

> User Info (tab)
>  Address (tab)
>         City (sub-tab)  
>      State (sub-tab)

So there will be two sub-tabs underneath the address tab (one with checkboxes of cities and another with checkboxes of states).

I googled for this problem and I [found a posting on the jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-tabs-is-nesting-possible) which describes a similar problem. The [posters created a sample/demo](http://jsbin.com/ubaqe) which had nested tabs and I've emulated their setup on my local webserver.

However, strangely, when I add a table to my nested tab, it appears outside the tabs on my page. (For example, in the div id="subtabs-1", if I add a table it doesn't appear inside the tabs when I load the page).

I think that my website may have other CSS which is causing the table element to be dislocated outside of the tabs. How would I identify what CSS is being applied to tables and which one is problematic? Or does anyone have another idea about what might be the problem? (Unfortunately, I can't link to my actual page since it is inside our intranet). Thanks.

Comment: [Just for your sanity, here's nested tabs with a nested table in one of the nested tabs.](http://jsfiddle.net/PLbUB/) -- Check your position: anything on the table, also ensure that your floats are cleared.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - thanks for the link. so it definitely must be some kind of CSS conflict in my site's specific css. I'll check around to see what else might be wrong.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that this is most likely a non-cleared float issue. Do you have any errors in your console? Like mismatched fragment identifiers, or some such?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - I added a div clear: both above and below the table - it still is broken. There is a library in my site which stripes the coloring of tr rows in html tables and it is probably the culprit. I'll have to look into removing it or tweaking it to not break the tables.